# Trapezoid with small divs evenly filled out

Tags: html, apache-flex, flex4

My requirement is that on an html page there should be a trapezoid bucket and it should get filled with drops (images). The no of drops is stored in a javascript variable.

I have tried the below code but it is not proper. The problem is with the small 50px by 50px divs(drop) which should fill the trapezoid evenly i.e. in the bottom they should be 4 per row then as we go up the no of divs per row should increase but they are not. Please suggest if this is possible by using html or using some other suitable tool can we do it ? Any suggestion welcome.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <style type="text/css">
    *, *:before, *:after{ 
    box-sizing: border-box; 
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
    } 
    .css-shapes-preview{ 
    position: relative; 
    height: 63px; 
    width: 281px; 
    padding: 0px; 
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg) skew(0deg); 
    transform: rotate(180deg) skew(0deg); 
    border-left: 60px solid transparent; 
    border-right: 60px solid transparent; 
    border-bottom: 300px solid #428BCA; 
    }
    </style>
    <div class="css-shapes-preview">
        <div style="height:50px;width:50px;border:1px solid black;float:left"> </div>
        <div style="height:50px;width:50px;border:1px solid black;float:left"> </div>
        <div style="height:50px;width:50px;border:1px solid black;float:left"> </div>
        <div style="height:50px;width:50px;border:1px solid black;float:left"> </div>
        <div style="height:50px;width:50px;border:1px solid black;float:left"> </div>
        <div style="height:50px;width:50px;border:1px solid black;float:left"> </div>
        <div style="height:50px;width:50px;border:1px solid black;float:left"> </div>
        <div style="height:50px;width:50px;border:1px solid black;float:left"> </div>
        <div style="height:50px;width:50px;border:1px solid black;float:left"> </div>
        <div style="height:50px;width:50px;border:1px solid black;float:left"> </div>
        <div style="height:50px;width:50px;border:1px solid black;float:left"> </div>
</div>
```